# double accounts

Tags: feature-request, bug

I used my open ID to log in twice today, both times I created a new account

https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2362/moak

https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2351/moak

Comment: @JeffAtwood, how can we properly keep/restore attributes of questions & answers for merged user accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Moak, I've merged your accounts into 2351, let us know if that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but now I lost ownership of this question and can't accept it as answered